# Replace Django Templates with ReactJs while Django serves as the API

Tags: django, reactjs, django-templates

I am trying to figure out the ideal approach to replace Django templates with ReactJS. When people say - "Let ReactJS entirely replace your Django Templates and let Django be used only as an API", they dont really mean replacing Django Templates (and the way they are served) entirely, right?

I mean my assumption is that the html pages will still be "served" through Django (as in, urls.py will still be used and point to an html template), and then in the template html, I can define a DOM node (div etc.) which React could use to populate its stuff in, yeah?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way too broad. Some people only use Django as an API backend, some people use traditional Django views and mix in some React components and some people aim for a middleground (https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a#.9rbul340a)

Comment: @arie My question is specifically about the case where Django is used as an API backend. I want to know what does it really mean to use Django as the API backend. Does it mean that the pages are not even "served" by Django (i.e they dont even get routed by urls.py and use a separate platform instead?) or does it mean using blank Django templates with just divs that are populated by components rendered by React. (Thanks for the hackernoon link - I do get the middleground path)

Comment: Both ways are possible. You (or another person/team) could create a completely independent frontend that is even served independently or you use Django to still serve some pages or the main page in case of an single page app. There's no fixed rule or way to do things, as it basically depends on your requirements and resources.